# ASP.NET: why avoid using GetService in a factory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, factory

Recenty I've found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1. It's about Dependency Injection in an ASP.NET Core application. There is a recommendation there, that I don't really understand:
*"Avoid injecting a factory that resolves dependencies at runtime using GetService."*

The problem is that such an approach might be useful. Suppose we have to create *N* instances of *Something* at runtime. So we could inject some factory in a *Client* class, which would use that factory to create *Something*. But what if *Something* has also some dependencies to resolve? That means that we would need to use *GetService* in our factory to resolve all dependencies. But in this manner we would use this anti-pattern, which we should avoid.

So my question is: why we should avoid explicitly calling *GetService*, and how could we implement something similar, but without *GetService*?

Comment: Using Autofac as an example, you could inject a `Func<Dependency>`. So it injects the _means to create_ the dependency (rather than the dependency itself. That would be preferable to Service Locator.

Comment: As it says `DI is an alternative to static/global object access patterns. You may not be able to realize the benefits of DI if you mix it with static object access.` Can you mix them? Sure. Will it end well? Likely not. Service Locator pattern, as a general rule, hides dependencies - and DI tries to do the opposite.

Comment: that is a general advice rather than a must. If you can avoid that, you should do that. Otherwise you can still inject a factory usually. In some cases involving `scoped dependencies/services`, you have to create a scope and `GetService` is what you need to get & use services just in the specific scope you create (at runtime).

Comment: @mjwills Thank you for your rapid responses, appreciate that. I see, so if I understood you correctly, the Client class might depend on lambda, which returns ISomething, and when needed we just invoke that lambda?

Comment: Exactly. https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html

Comment: Keep in mind, at uni you are dealing with _very small systems_. There might be 20 classes, total. I deal with systems where there might be 5,000 classes, and in one web request 300 classes may be involved, in a large and convoluted dependency tree. In those situations, DI makes life _way_ easier than service locator pattern. For small systems - anything is fine, kind of, since it is so small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft documentation is not wrong in advising this, but it is rather simplistic because it lacks a lot of context. I don't really blame the writers, because whole books on this topic can be written (which is [exactly what I did](https://mng.bz/BYNl)).

There is a lot to consider. An important first concept to understand, is the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). It is the part of the application where dependencies are registered, and object graphs get constructed.

Another important concept is the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). As the *anti-pattern* label implies, this is a pattern that should be always avoided. You are applying this anti-pattern when you allow code (that lives outside the Composition Root) to resolve *any* service. This will be the case, for instance, when you inject a `Func<Type, object>` delegate into a consumer, or when you inject the `IServiceProvider` into a consumer. Its `GetService` method has that delegate.

For code that lives *inside* the Composition Root, on the other hand, there is no notion of a Service Locator; this anti-pattern does not exist there. That's because the Composition Root's primary function is to construct types. It already has a direct dependency on the DI Container. The Composition Root is expected to resolve services.

It is important to note, however, that having a specific delegate is *not* the same as a Service Locator. For instance, if you inject an `Func<IMyService>`, this is *not* a Service Locator and, therefore, not a bad idea per see.

But there is more to consider. In general, you should define abstractions in such way that its consumers don't have to consider the number of instances. To reduce complexity from the view of the abstraction's consumers, those consumers should be able to call their abstractions as if there is only one instance.

This is not possible in all cases but can be considered a good rule of thumb. But when you apply this rule of thumb, there is little room for having factory abstractions (such as `Func<IMyService>`), as they immediately break this rule of thumb; the consumer actively creates multiple instances.

But even though the consumers might view their dependencies as stateless, the dependency's  implementations might not be. This still means these dependencies must be created at some point. And if you don't allow their consumers to do so, who can create them?

The answer to this question is: The **Composition Root**. In most cases, you should move the creation of dependencies out of application code and into the Composition Root.

Take for instance this `HomeController` that gets injected with a factory for creating `IProductRepository` :

```
public class HomeController
{
    private Func<IProductRepository> repoFactory;

    public HomeController(Func<IProductRepository> repoFactory)
    {
        this.repoFactory = repoFactory;
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var repository = this.repoFactory.Invoke();
        var products = repository.GetFeaturedProducts();
        return this.View(products);
    }
}
```

From perspective of `HomeController` there are two dependencies to consider: `Func<IProducerRepository>` and `IProductRepository`. This leads to complexity. From perspective of `HomeController`, a simpler solution would be the following:

```
public class HomeController
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public HomeController(IProductRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var products = this.repository.GetFeaturedProducts();
        return this.View(products);
    }
}
```

Although this simplifies the `HomeController`, it moves the problem around. But the idea is to move this complexity into the Composition Root.

Inside the Composition Root, for instance, you can create the following implementation:

```cs
public class ProductRepositoryProxy : IProductRepository
{
    private Func<IProductRepository> repoFactory;

    public ProductRepositoryProxy(Func<IProductRepository> repoFactory)
    {
        this.repoFactory = repoFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetFeaturedProducts()
    {
        var repository = this.repoFactory.Invoke();
        return repository.GetFeaturedProducts();
    }
}
```

This `ProductRepositoryProxy` wraps the original `Func<IProductRepository>` and invokes it on each call.

This `ProductRepositoryProxy` assumes that any `IProductRepository` implementation is stateful and should be short-lived. And this is fine because this knowledge is now centralized in the Composition Root. This simplifies the rest of the application can now focus on business decisions and less about dependency management.

This description is a short version of a longer discussion on *Abuse of Abstract Factories*, which can be found in section 6.2 of [my book](https://mng.bz/BYNl).

Comment: If the OP uses Autofac (for example) there is no need to have two separate `IProductRepository` implementations. Build the one, and Autofac will automagically support the `Func` scenario too. Also, in this specific scenario you have shown here, `Lazy` would likely be a better solution than `Func` (since you only want 0 or 1 instances of the repository). Or even action injection may be preferable. _Other than that, great answer._

Comment: @mjwills, there is so much more to talk about in this regard. I merely tried to illustrate why one should typically prevent using these factories (but the same holds for Lazy) outside the Composition Root. It's, however, hard to summarize this knowledge in a single SO answer. I apologise if I didn't succeed in doing so.

Comment: Great answer - thanks for putting it together.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understand you correctly.

Say you have 10 Classes that implement `ISomething`. You can register them with your ServiceCollection like this:

```
services.AddTransient<ISomething, Something1>();
services.AddTransient<ISomething, Something2>();
```

This way you implementations can also have dependencies but they are injected through your DI container.

If you want to inject all ISomething implementations in your class just inject them throught you constructor.

```
public class SomethingConsumer
{
    public SomethingConsumer(IEnumerable<ISomthing> somethingList)
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: no I don't think this is what the OP wants. The number of instances he wants to create is flexible, dynamic. He may want to create a dynamic number of instances of ***same service type*** at runtime.

Comment: ah, I see. No, that's not the right answer then.