# Dependency Injection circular dependency when using a Provider for interface implementations

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I'm currently facing an issue for which I have found some partial solutions, but not the one that actually makes me believe I cannot do better.

So, to put in simple, I'm using the Dependency Injection, and I'm facing a circular reference error. Here's something similar to the code I am using.

First, I have a `IMyBuilder` interface:

```
public interface IMyBuilder { }
```

Then, I have an abstract class that implements the interface, and a bunch of class extending the abstract one:

```
public abstract class MyBuilderBase<DTO> : IMyBuilder 
{
    public abstract Dto GetDto();
}

public class UserBuilderDto : MyBuilderDto<UserDTO> { ... }
public class ProfessorBuilderDto : MyBuilderDto<ProfessorDTO> { ... }
public class AnimalBuilderDto : MyBuilderDto<AnimalDTO> { ... }
```

Then, I have a `ProviderService`, which helps me get the right `IMyBuilder` based on the `DTO` type. This `ProviderService`depends on ALL the `IMyBuilder`, like so:

```
public class ProviderService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IMyBuilder> _builders;

    public ProviderService(IEnumerable<IMyBuilder> builders)
    {
        _builders = builder;
    }

    public IMyBuilder GetBuilder<DTO>()
    {
        return _builders.OfType<MyBuilderBase<DTO>>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Finally, last piece of my code is the registration of the services, like so:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyBuilder, UserBuilderDto>();
services.AddScoped<IMyBuilder, ProfessorBuilderDto>();
services.AddScoped<IMyBuilder, AnimalBuilderDto>();
services.AddScoped<ProviderService>();
```

Notice that I register my builder as `IMyBuilder`: this way I can use the parameter `IEnumerable<IMyBuilder>` in the constructor of `ProviderService`.

Ok, now that we have all the inputs, here's the problem: inside the abstract method `MyBuilderBase.GetDto` I might need some other builder! Therefore, `MyBuilderBase` needs `ProviderService`, something like this:

```
public class AnimalBuilderDto : MyBuilderDto<AnimalDTO>
{
    private readonly ProviderService _providerService;

    public AnimalBuilderDto(ProviderService providerService)
        => (_providerService) = (providerService)

    public AnimalDto GetDto()
    {
        // using _providerService
    }
}
```

At this point you can clearly see where is my problem:

1. `ProviderService` requires `AnimalBuilderDto`
2. `AnimalBuilderDto` requires `ProviderService`
3. `ProviderService` requires `AnimalBuilderDto`
4. ...
   Circular dependency, thus my application crashes.

---

So, I've investigated this for a while, and I've come up with these solutions.

1. **LAZY INITIALIZATION IN PROVIDER SERVICE**

This would be something like here: https://thomaslevesque.com/2020/03/18/lazily-resolving-services-to-fix-circular-dependencies-in-net-core/

Basically, in the constructor of `ProviderService` I would not directly need to initialize the single `IBuilderDto`, avoiding the circular dependency..

What I don't like is that it seems a workaround, and not a solution. Also, if by any chance I put a breakpoint into `providerService` constructor, and inspect the lazy property, the application crashes.. Yeah, workaround.

2. **METHOD INJECTION**

I would need to change the signature of the abstract method as follow:

```
public abstract Dto GetDto(ProviderService providerService);
```

This way, I would not need the `AnimalBuilderDto` to depends on `ProviderService`, REMOVING the circular dependency.
This solution seems a real solution (it removes the circular dependency), but it adds a cost, which is the need of bringing this instance of `ProviderService` along all the application in order to use it when calling `GetDto`.

---

Here's end my investigation. Though, both solution does not seems to fix my problem! Ok, the second one does actually fix the problem, but create another one, which is the need of bringing the instance across all method calls.

Question is: is there any better solution to make a provider class like my `ProviderService` being reusable inside the same classes that it exploses?

Comment: What members does `IMyBuilder` have? Can it not be generic itself?

Comment: Yes, it can be `IMyBuilder<DTO>`. Though, in the actual code has no members and is not generic, but it is used is "base" for different implementation of it. The code I wrote it's a sample. Though, I don't think this could change the circular dependency I'm having

Comment: So if `IMyBuilder` has no members, how do you use the result of `GetBuilder<DTO>`? Casting? If you injected a `IMyBuilder<TDto>`, and removed your `ProviderService`, then that would resolve the circular dependency.

Comment: Yes, I'm basically casting. There are reason to do so, again, this is a sample code.
I did thought about injecting `IMyBuilder<TDTO>`, but the problem is that it can happen that I need multiple builder, without knowing the `TDTO`. I may have an enumerable of `TDTO` where `TDTO` is a base abstract clas.. Therefore,  I would need different `IMyBuilder` at runtime, without knowing its type

Comment: In each builder, could you not inject all the `IMyBuilder<TDTO>`s that could possibly be needed? Rather than trying to resolve specific ones at runtime?

Comment: Again, I will not know all the builders I will need, since it will depends on some inputs. I may need an `AnimalBuilder` or a `PersonBuilder` or a `MachineBuilder`.. Who knows

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way to break the circular reference, using an open generic service locator factory.

```cs
public interface IMyBuilder<TDTO>
{
    TDTO GetDto();
}
public class BuilderFactory<TDTO>
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider services;
    public BuilderFactory(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        this.services = services;
    }
    public IMyBuilder<TDTO> GetBuilder() => services.GetRequiredService<IMyBuilder<TDTO>>();
}
public abstract class MyBuilderBase<DTO> : IMyBuilder<DTO>
{
    public abstract DTO GetDto();
}

public class UserDTO { }
public class UserBuilderDto : MyBuilderBase<UserDTO>
{
    private BuilderFactory<AnimalDTO> animalFactory;
    public UserBuilderDto(BuilderFactory<AnimalDTO> animalFactory)
    {
        this.animalFactory = animalFactory;
    }
    public override UserDTO GetDto()
    {
        var animalBuilder = animalFactory.GetBuilder();

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class AnimalDTO { }
public class AnimalBuilderDto : MyBuilderBase<AnimalDTO>
{
    private BuilderFactory<UserDTO> userFactory;
    public AnimalBuilderDto(BuilderFactory<UserDTO> userFactory)
    {
        this.userFactory = userFactory;
    }

    public override AnimalDTO GetDto()
    {
        var userBuilder = userFactory.GetBuilder();

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

services.AddScoped(typeof(BuilderFactory<>));
services.AddScoped<IMyBuilder<AnimalDTO>, AnimalBuilderDto>();
services.AddScoped<IMyBuilder<UserDTO>, UserBuilderDto>();
```

Comment: Thanks. Though, as you mentioned this is a "dirty" solution, and sometimes is also mentioned as an anti-pattern. What's most important is that `BuilderFactory` loses the actual depenendecies it needs (more difficulties when testing).
I would honestly prefer the Lazy approach over this, at least the dependencies would still be declared

Comment: You could scan the service collection and define the factory implementations explicitly, at least that would let you verify the dependencies properly. I've done something similar for singleton services that need to invoke scoped services inside some method.

Comment: It seems I could go with FactoryPattern, but in a little smarter way, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65494968/6070423
The idea is to have the `ServiceLocator` inside the CompositionRoot (which, in my case, should be the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method) and use `Func<IMyBuilder>`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event in consumer class and fire it , once fired make the server class return its current instance

Comment: Could you provide a code sample? I'm not sure I've understand what you meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the `Builders` use functions from `ProviderService` that use the `Builders` too, creating a factory is a way to break the cycle (at least in terms of timing, because the instances of the `Builders` are created at a later point in time and not upon registration.

However, if the `Builders` use only functions from `ProviderService` that do not rely on the `Builders` themselves, one other option is to move the functionality that is used in `GetDto` into another class that can be injected into both the `Builders` and the `ProviderService`. This way, the circular dependency is removed and both classes still have access to the functionality.

Basically, from

```
ProviderService -> Builders -> ProviderService
```

to

```
ProviderService -> Builders -> SharedFunctions
                -> SharedFunctions
```

Whether or not the `Builders` and the `ProviderService` use the same instance of `SharedFunctions` then depends on the scope that you register it in the IoC container.

Comment: Unfortunately, this cannot be done since `getDto` is typed on the generic type of `MyBuilderBase`, therefore by bringing the method outside I lose the typing.

Comment: @Jolly `GetDTO` should stay where it is; only the part in the method that uses the `ProviderService` class should be changed to use the `SharedFunctions` class instead.

Comment: Uhm, it seems to me I would still have a circular dependency. `ProviderService` would still depend from `Builders`. `Builders` would now depend from `SharedFunctions`. And `SharedFunctions` would depend from `ProviderService`.  Since `SharedFunctions` is injected in `Builder`constructor, the circular depenency is still there

Comment: @Jolly the central point is to move the functions from `ProviderService` to `SharedFunctions` that are used by the `Builders` and `ProviderService`. Then there is no dependency to `ProviderService` from the `Builders` anymore. If the `Builders` rely on functions from `ProviderService` that use the `Builders`, then this approach is not a way to go. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: That's not the case unfortunataely, therefore I cannot used a `SharedService`. I could use the factory pattern, but it would use the `IServiceProvider` if I'm not wrong, which would lead to the lose of the dependencies in the factory service (I mean, it would depend on `IServuceProvider` and not on the builder directly, which may cause difficulties in the tests